# How to manage services inside the container?

Tags: docker, centos

Systemctl/service commands are not working on a container which is built by using centos:centos7 image.

Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?  You may be able use a docker logs command to get the error message from the container if it isn't outputting it to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Using **systemd in Docker** is not really that straightforward.

However, [according to the doc on the docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos), **systemd** is now included in both the `centos:7` and `centos:latest` base containers.
However, you will need to include text similar to the example Dockerfile :

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

**I strongly recommend to read the full [description tab](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos?tab=description) documentation on the hub.** This will help you make it run correctly.